# Inserting related tables on laravel repository pattern

Tags: php, laravel, models

I have a products and skus table with the following models

### products

```
class Product extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;
    protected $table      = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'products_id';
    protected $fillable = ['user_profiles_id','is_app_ignored','product_name','product_description','tags','categories_id','image_count','is_active','is_shippable','creation_channels_id','is_admin_approved','users_id'];

    function skus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Sku','products_id');
    }
}
```

### skus

```
<?php

namespace App\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\Transformable;
use Prettus\Repository\Traits\TransformableTrait;
class Sku extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;
    protected $table      = 'skus';
    protected $primaryKey = 'skus_id';
    protected $fillable = ['products_id','quantity','actual_price','selling_price','quantity_sold','quantity_type','quantity_total','bucket_value','currency','condition','sort_order'];

    function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Product','products_id');
    }
}
```

This is the data which need to be inserted

```
[categories_id] => 1
    [product_name] => Pen
    [product_description] => this is a pen
    [tags] => pn,write
    [image_count] => 4
    [product_code] => ABCD
    [is_app_ignored] => y
    [creation_channels_id] => 123
    [skus] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [is_shippable] => y
                    [actual_price] => 100.55
                    [selling_price] => 150.54
                    [quantity_type] => finite
                    [quantity_total] => 10
                    [bucket_value] => 
                    [sort_order] => 1
                )

        )

    [users_id] => 1
    [user_profiles_id] => 1
```

The products values will have to go to the products table and the skus details has to be inserted into the skus table with the products_id in the skus table.

How this can be done in the repository pattern. The repository pattern I am following is

[L5 Repository pattern](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)

Answer (score -1):

Your product:

```
function skus()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Sku','skus_id');
}
```

Your Skus:

```
function product()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\Product','products_id');
}
```

First save the products:

```
$product = new Product($request->all());
$product->save();
```

and then save the skus:

```
$product = Product::find($product->id);
$product->skus()->create($request->all());
```

All this method you need to make sure the field is `$fillable`.

Comment: Why did you need to find the already loaded product?
Just use the object $product.
And you don't need to create skus, just attach before save it:
´´´
$product->skus()->attach($skusArray);
´´´